Issues with wxWidgets and Binding on Mac M1
This is my first question so I hope I follow the corrrect steps.
Summary:
Installed wxWidgets on an M1 Macbook Pro running macOS Sonoma 14.4.1.
Successfully compiled and ran several demos/samples. (Clang)
I then made a copy of the Hello World sample and started modifying it in an attempt to educate myself on wxWidgets.
I added a button widget, which appears when I compile and run.
However, when I try to bind the button I get the dreaded architecture error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyFrame::onOkButton(wxCommandEvent&)", referenced from:
      MyFrame::MyFrame() in hello_tests-3e1e88.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've tried two different binding methods, see the commented lines in the code.
I may not be following the right steps in posting. Apologies in advance.
Here is the code:
// Start of wxWidgets "Hello World" Program
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/button.h>


class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() override;
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();

private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void onOkButton(wxCommandEvent& event);
};

enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1
};

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame()
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Hello World")
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
                     "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);

    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);

    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");

    SetMenuBar( menuBar );

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");

    //first attempt at adding a widget to the frame - SW 4/20/24
    //
    wxButton* myButton  = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, ("MyButton" ), wxPoint(10, 20), wxSize(80,30));


    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
    //Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::onOkButton);
    //myButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::onOkButton, this);
}

void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example",
                 "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}

void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}

void onOkButton(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("Button Test",
                 "About This App", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}



I forgot to post the clang command line that I am using: clang++ -std=c++17 hello_tests.cpp -o testbutton ./wx-config --cxxflags --libs

You forgot the MyFrame:: in front of onOkButton.

@Siguza you should submit this as the answer.

@SJWoodward, this is called cut'n'paste error...

Thank you very much @Siguza and Igor, you have solved the question for me. I had a feeling I was overlooking something simplistic.

@VZ. nah, just vote to close as typo.

Again I'm new here. If @Siguza would like me to accept his answer I would be more than happy to do so, but if I'm not mistaken it has to be submitted as the answer?
